# Rounding UP to the nearest .5 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I was if anyone can let me know how I can round UP to the nearest .5

Currently my implementation rounds either up or down but I want to have it round up at all times.

Here is my current implementation.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    doTheMath('0.3','1.6','2.4','3.0')
});

function doTheMath(num1,num2,num3,num4){
var n1 = (Math.round(num1 * 2) / 2).toFixed(1);
var n2 = (Math.round(num2 * 2) / 2).toFixed(1);
var n3 = (Math.round(num3 * 2) / 2).toFixed(1);
var n4 = (Math.round(num4 * 2) / 2).toFixed(1);

$('#show_numbers').text(n1+"| "+n2+"| "+n3+"| "+n4);
}
```

html

```
<div id="show_numbers"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qF6nj/

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Have you already checked all the other methods of `Math.`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XB3ZY/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `Math.ceil` this will always round up. Where `Math.floor` will always round down.

```
var n1 = (Math.ceil(num1 * 2) / 2).toFixed(1);
```

Comment: Ah perfect Math.celi! Learned something new! Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to be precise: ceil() and floor() don't really "round", they just cut of the decimal places.